# Unity Sqlite local database strange letters on Android

Tags: android, sqlite, unity-game-engine, arabic

I'm trying to create a questions game using Unity and Sqlite-database 
Unfortunately Unity doesn't support Arabic language 
so if i want to add some text like

```
**السلام عليكم **
```

i need to use this website 
[Support Arabic for programs that are not supported](https://omar84.com/docs/taw/arabic_writer.html)
add the letters in the Input and get the output from it and add it in Unity .
everything is working fine on a lot of devices including my device 
but when i asked some friends to try it on their devices they show me a 
strange letters showing up instead of Arabic letters
What the app show in my device **Samsung grand Duos** 
[image: What the app show in my device]

But in some devices like **HUAWEI Y7 Prime**
[image: But in some devices like] it shows differently.

I did a lot of search and i think it's Sqlite problem because 
i did enter the data in the same way in Unity and Sqlite 
when i fetch data in Unity it works fine 
but when i tried to fetch data from Sqlite it shows the strange letters 
any help ?

thanks in Advance

Comment: Looks like your app is sending utf-8 text to something that's treating it like latin-1 or another single byte encoding.

Comment: thanks for your replay .
any idea about how to solve this ?

Comment: [Try this asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/arabic-support-for-unity-2674)

Comment: it didn't work i tried it before , but thanks for any way

Comment: Send this pragma before you create the database.  https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_encoding